# Displaying vCard photos in Windows Contacts

Tags: windows, windows-7, contacts, vcf-vcard

Following vCard 2.1, I'm adding photos to vCards. I'm encoding the image fetched from a URL, then adding the encoded value to the proper place within the vCard. This seemingly displays the photo correctly for all programs that can open vCards except the Windows Contacts program on Windows 7 (probably doesn't work for newer versions of Windows either).

As far as I can tell, the below snippet should display the vcard photo when opened in Windows Contacts:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:Lastname;Firstname;
FN;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:Firstname Lastname
ORG;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1: Organization LLP
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=jpg: <base64 encoded image as one line>
TITLE;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:Position
TEL;WORK;VOICE:+1 999 999 9999
END:VCARD
```

All the other information displays in Windows Contacts, but not the photo. The standard blank image placeholder displays.

I have tried

- `ENCODING=BASE64`
- ommitting the `ENCODING` keyword altogether
- removing the `TYPE` keyword altogether
- using specifically a 240px by 240px image
- adding the image URL value in the file instead of the encoded value

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: leaving this up for a little while at least, but the consensus seems to be that it is not possible to have a photo display in a vCard that's opened in Windows Contacts, at least for Windows 7+. I'll probably file a bug report

Answer (score 1):

- Version 2.1 uses `ENCODING=BASE64`.
- Put an empty line after the PHOTO property.  Outlook requires this, so Contacts might too.
- Put all parameter names/values in upper case.  I know of one compatibility problem with Windows Contacts where it doesn't recognize a parameter value if it's in lower case.
- Remove the space character before the base64 data.
- Try setting the TYPE parameter to JPEG.
- You've correctly encoded the image data, right?  Try using an online decoder to make sure.

Corrected property:

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:<base64 encoded image as one line>
[empty line]
```

According to the specs, if you have a URL, you should set the VALUE parameter to URL.

`PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;VALUE=URL:<url goes here>`

Comment: I tried all your suggestions and unfortunately they did not work, I still just see the blank image placeholder when I open the vCard in Windows Contacts. I'm beginning to think this might be a bug in Contacts or Contacts doesn't support images in vCard files (only in .CONTACT files, which are XML)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into your post while researching this question and I was able to successfully find the correct way to achieve this.

Bellow is a self-containing example of a v-card containing an 96x96 embedded red.gif image as the PHOTO.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426#section-3.1.4

Be sure to note the VERSION line and the PHOTO line. This is currently working in Outlook365.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest;;Mr.;
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=GIF:R0lGODdhYABgAPAAALccHMlFJiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAABgAGAAAAJuhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJjUqn1Kr1is1qt9yu9wsOi8fksvmMTqvX7Lb7DY/L5/S6/Y7P6/f8vv8PGCg4SFhoeIiYqLiIUgAAOw==
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212
TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212
ADR;TYPE=WORK;PREF=1;LABEL="100 Waters Edge\nBaytown\, LA 30314\nUnited States of America":;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
ADR;TYPE=HOME;LABEL="42 Plantation St.\nBaytown\, LA 30314\nUnited States of America":;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
x-qq:21588891
END:VCARD
```

[image: image1]